# how to get inserted/updated object after inserting/updating with jooq generated dao

Tags: java, database, dao, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I generated DictOrgDao from dict_org table in my postgres DB, using jooq code generation tool. This dao has common methods like insert and update but they all return void. Is there any way to get inserted/updated object after inserting/updating with jooq generated dao?

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box if your POJOs are mutable. Here are the relevant flags in `Settings`:

- [`Settings.returnRecordToPojo`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#returnRecordToPojo) (default is `true`): mutable POJOs should automatically be updated with generated keys.
- [`Settings.returnIdentityOnUpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#returnIdentityOnUpdatableRecord) (default is `true`): generated identity values are returned on `INSERT`
- [`Settings.returnAllOnUpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#returnAllOnUpdatableRecord) (default is `false`): generated default and trigger generated values are returned on `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `MERGE`

Comment: Hi Lukas, is there a way to get this working for immutable kotlin data classes? e.g new pojo is returned instead?

Comment: @NayeemZen: Is this really the same question? Better ask a new one or create a bug if you think there's a bug.